# How to Simply Ajax Script (Removing duplicate code)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to simplify the following script, and create a reuseable funciton,
I use it with:

```
<span id="test"></span>
<span id="abc"></span>
<span id="123"></span>
```

here it is now:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var callAjax = function(){
      $.ajax({
        method:'get',
        url:'abctest.php',
        success:function(data){
          $("#test").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
    setInterval(callAjax,1000);
  });  

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var callAjax = function(){
      $.ajax({
        method:'get',
        url:'getabc.php',
        success:function(data){
          $("#abc").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
    setInterval(callAjax,1000);
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var callAjax = function(){
      $.ajax({
        method:'get',
        url:'123.php',
        success:function(data){
          $("#123").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
    setInterval(callAjax,1000);
  });
</script>
```

as you can see, all I need is to change the url and #, so I create a function:

```
function good(url,tag){
    var callAjax = function(){
      $.ajax({
        method:'get',
        url:'url.php',
        success:function(data){
          $("#tag").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
    setInterval(callAjax,1000);
  }
```

and rewrite the script to:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(good(abctest,test));
$(document).ready(good(getabc,abc));
$(document).ready(good(123,123));
</script>
```

looks much better. but seems not so easy.
it not working. how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your almost there. You need to manually concatenate the strings like

```
function good(url,tag){
    var callAjax = function(){
      $.ajax({
        method:'get',
        url:url+'.php',
        success:function(data){
          $("#"+tag).html(data);
        }
      });
    }
    setInterval(callAjax,1000);
  }
```

`Javascript` is not like `php` where variables can be evaluated between double quotes.

Also, you need to pass your parameters in as strings

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    good('abctest','test');
    good('getabc','abc');
    good('123','123');
});
```